# Best app to read rss feed in real time

Tags: macos, ios, software-recommendation, desktop, rss

Could someone help to find best free / paid Mac OS or iOS (or both) app for reading rss feed in real time? I want the recent posts to appear at the top of screen with time, date and source. Also it should be minimalistic and functional design, ability to search and filter with key words. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Reeder](http://reederapp.com/) for some time now, it's pretty easy to use. There is a version for iOS and OS X. You can find all you're looking for in the settings section.

Image :

[image]

Comment: Does new posts appear at the top of table in real time? I see only refresh option, which is not as I'm looking for. Does it have some searching, filtering functions?

Comment: it have a search option, refreshing is minimum 5 min